# Android Wifi Scan - BroadcastReceiver for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, android-broadcast, wifimanager

Here is my code:

```
public class FloatWifiManager implements IWifiManager {

    private WifiManager wifiManager;

    private BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver;

    public FloatWifiManager(Context context) {
        ...
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // Registering Wifi Receiver
        wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                    // not getting called, only after running app and manually going to the wifi settings in android
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
```

I registered the `BroadcastReceiver` exactly like I saw in all the examples, and did `startScan`.

What happens is, the **wifi list** is changing (for sure, I tested), but `onReceive` is not called if I just stay in the app.

What makes `onReceive` finally to be called - is to launch the app, leave it running, and going in the android phone to **Settings** -> **Wifi settings**. when going there, all of the sudden the List is updating and `onReceive` is called.

What's the problem here?

1. Does  `wifiManager.startScan();` runs the scan only once? or it is a function that keeps listening to incoming "Scan Results"?
2. And obviously, why does the receiver doesn't get called?

Comment: did u find any solution??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `startScan()` requests only one single scan.

You can get rid of the `if (intent.getAction().equals(..))` condition. Anything else seems to be ok.

> just to make it clear - my goal to have a receiver that will get
>   called every time the Wifi networks list are changing, without having
>   to click a "start scan" button.

AFAIK it is not possible to get notified whenever any of the wifi networks change. You can only request a scan with `startScan` - and of course you can call `startScan` repeatedly using a Thread or Handler.

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) say that `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` is called when *"an access point scan has completed, and results are available from the supplicant"*. How and when a scan is proceeded depends on the implemention of the supplicant. [Elenkov](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2631372) writes, that *"Android devices rarely include the original wpa_supplicant code; the included implementation is often modified for better compatibility with the underlying SoC"*.

---

**Scan for access points**

This example scans for available access points and ad hoc networks. `btnScan` activates a scan initiated by the `WifiManager.startScan()` method. After  the scan, `WifiManager` calls the `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` intent and the `WifiScanReceiver` class processes the scan result. The results are displayed in a `TextView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    TextView txtWifiInfo;
    WifiManager wifi;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReceiver = new WifiScanReceiver();

        txtWifiInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWifiInfo);
        Button btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Start scan...");
                wifi.startScan();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(
            wifiReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
        );
        super.onResume();
    }

    private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
            txtWifiInfo.setText("");
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                String info = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
                txtWifiInfo.append(info+"\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Permissions**

The following permissions need to be defined in *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

`android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` is necessary for calling `WifiManager.getScanResults()`. Without `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` you cannot initiate a scan with `WifiManager.startScan()`.

When compiling the project for api level 23 or greater (Android 6.0 and up), either `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` must be inserted. Furthermore that permission needs to be requested, e.g. in the `onCreate` method of your main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String[] PERMS_INITIAL={
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    };
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMS_INITIAL, 127);
}
```

Comment: what I meant by asking if its a "single scan" was - will I keep getting notified in onResponse when Wifi networks are updating? it seems that it does - because when I run the code and just go to the Settings -> Wifi Settings, the onResponse  is getting called multiple times. so, just to make sure, it is not necessary to call startScan() multiple times , once is enough, correct?

Comment: just to make it clear - my goal to have a receiver that will get called every time the Wifi networks list are changing, without having to click a "start scan" button.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so, as far as you know, it can't be done without calling it repeatedly? my goal is actually to listen to changes in availability for only one Specific network with a Specific SSID. I asked about the whole network list because I figured that's the only way to do it (go over the list and check my specific network), but maybe there is a way to listen to availability changes for a specific network? thanks a million

Comment: Yes, considering the `xxx_ACTION`s the Android Wifi API provides I don't think there's any other way but scanning repeatedly. You can listen for changes of the *current* connected network with `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` but you can't restrict this to a specific SSID.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks a lot!