# Does not get any wifi network with using WifiManager

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am using WifiManager to get a list of available wifi networks.

This is my method:

```
 public List<ScanResult> getWifiInRange() {

    //scan for wifis
    wifiMgr.startScan();

    // gets ~last~ list of WiFi networks accessible through the access point.
    return (wifiScan = (List<ScanResult>) wifiMgr.getScanResults());
  }
```

But this method doesn't retun any wifi networks on some devices!

For example, when I using this method on Asus_p024 it works correctly and returns a list of available wifi networks But on Samsung Tab-s it returns 0 items!

**Update**

I just changed my code and implement a broadcast like this:

```
public class WifiBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      List<ScanResult> mScanResults = wifi.getScanResults();

      wifiList = wifi.getScanResults();
      netCount = wifiList.size();

      Log.d("Wifi", "Total Wifi Network" + netCount);

    }
  }
```

I still it can't get a list of available wifi networks.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering a BroadcastReceiver for `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455722/android-wifi-scan-broadcastreceiver-for-scan-results-available-action-not-gett). The docs for `WifiManager.getScanResults()` say:

> Return the results of the latest access point scan.

So we don't have certainty that the result of the latest scan is available at the call to `getScanResults()`

Answer (score 1):

Pleae check that you have included the following permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Additionally, for API 23+, permissions must be requested at runtime.